# CHECK constraint to enforce ###.###.#### pattern match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraint

I would like to have a check constraint that enforces this regex pattern for a multi-part code:

```
^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4}$
```

...three numbers, a period, three numbers, a period, four numbers.

Do I need to create a CLR function to enforce the pattern matching, and can the CLR function be referenced in DDL?

Is there a way to enforce the pattern in another way, using `LIKE`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The regex in your question is [not entirely unambiguous](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

> In most flavors that support Unicode, \d includes all digits from all
>   scripts. Notable exceptions are Java, JavaScript, and PCRE. These
>   Unicode flavors match only ASCII digits with \d.

So in many flavours it would match `١١١.١١١.١١١١` (that character being [Arabic-Indic Digit One](http://unicode-table.com/en/0661/))

I'm assuming that you just want to match latin `0-9`. You can use

```
DECLARE  @T TABLE
(
Col CHAR(12) CHECK (
                   Col LIKE REPLACE('ddd.ddd.dddd','d','[0-9]') 
                                  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
                   )
)
```

I'm using the binary collate clause so strings like `¾¾¾.¾¾¾.¾¾¾¾` or `10².10².1000` don't pass the check ([as can happen on some collations](http://rextester.com/KUWM67220)).

Neither of these would match the desired CLR regex and although using the set syntax (`[0123456789]`) rather than the range syntax (`[0-9]`) resolves the first one  it is still collation dependent whether `2` matches `²` or not.

I'm using `REPLACE` rather than hard-coding the `LIKE` pattern because I find it more readable what the pattern is checking. It is easier to see three digits and a dot followed by three digits another dot then four digits in that format than parsing `[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9] [0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

It also makes it easier to swap out implementation.

I you do decide that you want the full blown semantics of the CLR regular expression after all you could just change `'[0-9]'` above to the below (and likely change the column to `NCHAR(12)` in that case)

```
'[' +
 /*48-57 Basic Latin*/
N'0-9'+
 /*1632-1641 Arabic-Indic*/
N'٠-٩'+
 /*1776-1785 Extended Arabic-Indic*/
N'۰-۹'+
 /*1984-1993 Nko*/
N'߀-߉'+
 /*2406-2415 Devanagari*/
N'०-९'+
 /*2534-2543 Bengali*/
N'০-৯'+
 /*2662-2671 Gurmukhi*/
N'੦-੯'+
 /*2790-2799 Gujarati*/
N'૦-૯'+
 /*2918-2927 Oriya*/
N'୦-୯'+
 /*3046-3055 Tamil*/
N'௦-௯'+
 /*3174-3183 Telugu*/
N'౦-౯'+
 /*3302-3311 Kannada*/
N'೦-೯'+
 /*3430-3439 Malayalam*/
N'൦-൯'+
 /*3558-3567 Sinhala*/
N'෦-෯'+
 /*3664-3673 Thai*/
N'๐-๙'+
 /*3792-3801 Lao*/
N'໐-໙'+
 /*3872-3881 Tibetan*/
N'༠-༩'+
 /*4160-4169 Myanmar*/
N'၀-၉'+
 /*4240-4249 Myanmar Shan*/
N'႐-႙'+
 /*6112-6121 Khmer*/
N'០-៩'+
 /*6160-6169 Mongolian*/
N'᠐-᠙'+
 /*6470-6479 Limbu*/
N'᥆-᥏'+
 /*6608-6617 New Tai Lue*/
N'᧐-᧙'+
 /*6784-6793 Tai Tham Hora*/
N'᪀-᪉'+
 /*6800-6809 Tai Tham Tham*/
N'᪐-᪙'+
 /*6992-7001 Balinese*/
N'᭐-᭙'+
 /*7088-7097 Sundanese*/
N'᮰-᮹'+
 /*7232-7241 Lepcha*/
N'᱀-᱉'+
 /*7248-7257 Ol Chiki*/
N'᱐-᱙'+
 /*42528-42537 Vai*/
N'꘠-꘩'+
 /*43216-43225 Saurashtra*/
N'꣐-꣙'+
 /*43264-43273 Kayah Li*/
N'꤀-꤉'+
 /*43472-43481 Javanese*/
N'꧐-꧙'+
 /*43504-43513 Myanmar Tai Laing*/
N'꧰-꧹'+
 /*43600-43609 Cham*/
N'꩐-꩙'+
 /*44016-44025 Meetei Mayek*/
N'꯰-꯹'+
 /*65296-65305 Fullwidth*/
N'０-９'+
N']'  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
```